# mdadm error: found two disks with the number 0

Tags: debian, raid, debian-squeeze, mdadm

Im running a server deep in the forest , and after a hard disco failure i got this error.
error: found two disks with the number 0.

It a server with 2, 1 TB disc in raid 1 with mdadm 0.9
SDA failed and mdadm swap to SDB, i change the hard drive, re-add the member and the sync process began.

But now i got this errors everytime i want to reinstall grub on sda in case sdb got broken.

```
mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
   Version : 0.90
 Creation Time : Wed May  9 18:18:09 2012
 Raid Level : raid1
 Array Size : 944750400 (900.98 GiB 967.42 GB)
 Used Dev Size : 944750400 (900.98 GiB 967.42 GB)
 Raid Devices : 2
 Total Devices : 2
 Preferred Minor : 0
 Persistence : Superblock is persistent

 Update Time : Thu Dec 12 22:54:17 2013
      State : clean
Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

       UUID : 34657f17:a9b6b7c0:445bc27b:76f0785c
     Events : 0.15638170

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
 0       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
 1       8       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2


grub-install /dev/sda
error: found two disks with the number 0.
error: found two disks with the number 0.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
Auto-detection of a filesystem of /dev/md0 failed.
Please report this together with the output of "/usr/sbin/grub-probe --device-     map=/boot/grub/device.map --target=fs -v /boot/grub" to <bug-grub@gnu.org>


12/12/2013 23:06:33 root@srv156:[/home/backup/data/postgres]# grub-probe -v / 
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 1953525168.
error: found two disks with the number 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd1 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd1 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd1 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd1 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd1 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd1 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd1 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd1 is 1953525168.
grub-probe: info: changing current directory to /dev.
grub-probe: info: changing current directory to dri.
grub-probe: info: changing current directory to snd.
grub-probe: info: changing current directory to by-path.
grub-probe: info: changing current directory to net.
grub-probe: info: changing current directory to shm.
grub-probe: info: changing current directory to openvpn_as.
grub-probe: info: changing current directory to memstats.
grub-probe: info: changing current directory to pso.
grub-probe: info: changing current directory to network.
grub-probe: info: opening md0.
grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
```

Any idea?

Debian Squeeze

Thanks!

PS: i saw on different post that the problems comes from a bad superblock at the end of the disc, but really i dont know how to proceed.

Comment: you might want to look at this: https://wiki.frugalware.org/index.php/GRUB2

Comment: Uffff.....nice thing to do. I had the errors that indicated that i muss recreate the array. Sweeeet.